# Bases for the closed sets

Tags: general-topology

I don't understand what the author means when he says that $F_1\cup F_2$ is an intersection of elements of $\mathcal{F}$.  I would think it means that $F_1 \cup F_2 = \bigcap_{F\in \mathcal{F}} F$, but (b) says $\bigcap_{F\in \mathcal{F}} F=\emptyset$

[image]

Comment: See [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3586091/4280) on how to solve 5E, and which also gives the right interpretation for (a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big difference between

> An intersection of elements in $\mathscr F$

and

> The intersection of all elements in $\mathscr F$

We want there to be some subset $\mathscr E\subseteq \mathscr F$ so that $F_1\cup F_2 = \bigcap_{F\in\mathscr E}F$. However, many times, and in particular if $F_1$ and $F_2$ have points in common, $\mathscr E$ will not be all of $\mathscr F$

Comment: did you mean generalized intersection? ie $F_1 \cup F_2 = \bigcap_{F\in\mathscr E}F $

Comment: @jacques99 Yes, I meant intersection there. Sorry.

Comment: OK thank you very much