# Prove that the compact-open topology is finer than the pointwise topology.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, solution-verification, compactness

Let $(Y,d)$ a metric space and $(X,\cal T)$ a topological space so that for any $A\in\cal T_d$ and for any compact $K\in\mathcal P(X)$ we put
$$
S(K,A):=\{f\in Y^X:f[K]\subseteq A\}
$$so that we define the collection
$$
\mathcal S:=\{S(K,A):(K,A)\in\cal K\times T_d\}
$$
where $\cal K$ is the collection of compact spaces of $X$ with respect $\cal T$. So we observe that the empty set is (trivially) compact and thus if $Y$ is open then any $f\in Y^X$ is an element of $S(\emptyset,Y)$ so that $\cal S$ is a subbase for a topology $\mathcal T_K$ which we call compact-open topology.

Now Munkres says that the compact open topology is finer that pointwise topology $\cal T_p$, which we remember is just the product topology: so if $f\in A$ with $A\in\cal T_p$ then there exists $x_1,\dots,x_n\in X$ with $n\in\omega$ and $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ such that
$$
f\in\bigcap_{i=1}^n\pi^{-1}_{x_i}\Big[B\big(f(x_i),\epsilon\big)\Big]\subseteq A
$$
so that for any $i=1,\dots ,n$ let's we put
$$
K_i:={x_i}\quad\text{and}\quad B_i:=B\big(f(x_i),\epsilon\big)
$$
and thus let's we prove that
$$
\tag{1}\label{1}f\in S_f\subseteq\bigcap_{i=1}^n\pi^{-1}_{x_i}\Big[B\big(f(x_i),\epsilon\big)\Big]
$$
where we put
$$
S_f:= \bigcap_{i=1}^n S(K_i,B_i)
$$
So we observe that $f(x_i)$ lies in $B\big(f(x_i),\epsilon\big)$ for any $i=1,\dots,n$ so that for any $i=1,\dots,n$ the inclusion
$$
f[K_i]\subseteq B_i
$$
holds and so $f$ lies in $S_f$; however, if $g$ lies in $S_f$ then for any $i=1,\dots, n$ the inclusion
$$
g[K_i]\subseteq B_i
$$
holds but we know that
$$
g[K_i]=\{g(x_i)\}=\{\pi_{x_i}(g)\}
$$
so that $g$ lies in $\pi^{-1}_{x_i}\Big[B\big(f(x_i),\epsilon\big)\Big]$ or rather in $\bigcap_{i=1}^n\pi^{-1}_{x_i}\Big[B\big(f(x_i),\epsilon\big)\Big]$.

So \eqref{1} proves that any open set of $\cal T_p$ is union of open set of $\mathcal T_K$ so that we finally conclude that
$$
\mathcal T_p\subseteq\mathcal T_K
$$

Well, first of all I would like to know if I well proved that $\cal S$ is a subase and $\cal T_p$ is contained in $\mathcal T_K$ and then I would like if it is possible to prove these things in another more simple way: could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little unsure of what you're asking, but here's my best interpretation.

1. Did you prove that $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbase? I'm not totally sure what you are asking here. The compact-open topology is generally defined to be the smallest topology containing the subsets you defined, so by definition it is a subbasis. Do you have a different definition of the compact-open topology that you are working with?
2. Did you prove $\mathcal{T}_p \subseteq \mathcal{T}_K$? Outside of some typos, it looks good to me.
3. Could your proof be improved? I think the following is a little faster, but a proof should be about understanding and not optimization.

Let
$$\mathcal{B}_p := \{\pi_x^{-1}(B_\epsilon(y))  \ | \ x \in X, y \in Y, \epsilon > 0\}.$$
This is a subbasis for $\mathcal{T}_p$. Notice that $\pi_x^{-1}(B_\epsilon(y)) = S(\{x\}, B_\epsilon(y)),$ so $\mathcal{B}_p \subseteq \mathcal{S}$ and hence $\mathcal{T}_p \subseteq \mathcal{T}_K$.

Comment: Okay, so to be more precisely you observed that the equality $$
\pi_x^{-1}(B_\epsilon(y))=\{f\in Y^X:\pi_x(f)\in B_\epsilon(y)\}=\{f\in Y^X:f(x)\in B(\epsilon(y)\}=\{f\in Y^x:f[x]\subseteq B_\epsilon(y)\}=S\big(\{x\},B_\epsilon(y)\big)
$$ hods so that $\cal S$ so that $\cal B_p$ is contained in $S$ and thus any open set of $\cal T_p$ is and open set of $\mathcal T_K$, right?

Comment: Anyway you understood: I tried to prove that $\cal S$ is a subbase and thus I asked if I did it well. So did I well prove that $\cal S$ is a subbase? Indeed I know that a collection is a subbase of any topology if and only it it is a cover: is this true?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Your last comment is not correct.  Any collection of subsets of a set $X$ is a subbase for the topology on $X$ that it generates, by definition.  It does not matter that the subsets cover $X$ or not.  By definition, the topology that the subbase generates is the smallest topology containing the subbase, which always exists, namely as the intersection of all topologies containing the subbase.  The article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase has more details about this topic.

Comment: @PatrickR Sorry, but I do not understand well what is my mistake: indeed, if $\cal S$ is a subbase for a topology $\cal T$ in a set $X$ then for any $x∈X$ there exist $S_1,…,S_n∈S$ with $n∈ω$ such that
$$x∈S_1∩⋯∩S_n⊆⋃S$$
which proves that $\cal S$ cover $X$; conversely, if $\cal S$ cover $X$ then the collection of finite intersection of $\cal S$ is a base for a topology on $X$ because it is closed for finite intersection and because it covers $X$. So as you can see a collection $S$ is a subbase for a topology in $X$ if and only it covers $X$: are you again think I am wrong?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro A subbase for a topology on $X$ need not cover $X$.  Take a look at the two (equivalent) definitions of subbase in wikipedia.  Def 1 says that the subbase generates the topology.  Def 2 says that the set of finite intersections of elements of the subbase form a base for the topology. These finite intersections include the intersection of the empty subfamily, which is the whole space $X$.  But the subbase itself need not cover $X$.

Comment: @PatrickR Well, unfortunately (at least I know this) the intersection of empty set is not defined in **ZF** as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4486876/736008) is proved. Anyway I reaffirm that if $\cal S$ is a subbase for $X$ equipped with a topology $\cal T$ then by the wiki definition $2$ and by opennes of $X$ for any $ x∈X$ there exist $S_1,…,S_n∈\cal S$ not empty (**the intersection of the empty set is not defined!!!!**) with $n∈ω$ such that $$x∈S_1∩⋯∩S_n⊆⋃S$$ and this clearly proves that $\cal S$ cover $X$ by arbitrariness of $x∈X$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)#Nullary_intersection.  It is true that the intersection of an empty family is not defined as a set in ZF, as it would have to be the whole universe, which is not a set.  But in the context of a fixed enclosing set $X$ on which we want to define a topology, the intersection of the empty family of subsets of $X$ makes perfect sense, and it is $X$ (run through the definition of intersection of a family and you will see).  Also notice the sentence with "nullary intersection convention" after Def 2 in wiki.

Comment: @PatrickR Okay, so substantially (for confirmation) a subbase could be not a cover putting **informally** that $$\bigcap\emptyset:=X$$ right?

Comment: Right, it need not be a cover.  But there is nothing informal about the empty intersection of a family of subsets of a set.  It's just a fact that is easy to prove: Suppose $\mathscr{A}$ is a collection of subsets of $X$. The set $\bigcap\mathscr{A}$ consists of those $x\in X$ that belong to all $A\in\mathscr{A}$.  If $\mathscr{A}$ is empty, all $x\in X$ vacuously satisfy that, since there are no $A\in\mathscr{A}$.

Comment: @PatrickR Well, surely your arguments work (apparently) but unfortunately they do not agree with **ZF** formalism as explained in the above linked hartkp's answer and as in your comment above you implicitly "preannounced" so that with respect **ZF** I think it is better to put $$⋂∅:=X$$ justifying the above position with your last arguments. However I think this could be a bit tedious discussion: at this point it is clear why with respect your definition a subbase could be not a cover whereas with respect my definition it must be it. So thanks for the discussion: I learnt a lot! ;-)

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro You are welcome.  Also, if you don't like to make use of the intersection of the empty family, that's fine.  In that case, note that in Def 2 in wikipedia they are careful to add the phrase "together with the set X" in the first sentence.  That's needed so that Def 2 matches Def 1.  Also note in the next sentence "every **proper** open set in T can be written ...", again hinting to the fact that if you don't start with a cover, you have to add X explicitly to the topology.